# building angular app with webpack by seeing medium forum

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

- i am trying to build my angular application using webpack.
- so I referred this link https://medium.com/@aikeru/getting-started-with-angular-2-webpack-typescript-788b793d7771
- i created a webpack.config.js at package.json level and in package.json I included this line "bundle": "webpack"
- wh**en I run npm run bundle I am facing an error Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.**
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code and eror below

**folder structure**

```
- webapp
  - app
    - app.module.ts
  - package.json
  -webpack.config.js
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import './rxjs-extensions';

import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';

import {Base} from './components/base/base';
import {players} from './components/jumping/user';

require('./directives/yep-nope.controller');
require('./services/github-status.service');
require('./controllers/dashboard.controller');

import {
    Routes,
    RouterModule,
    Router,
    ActivatedRoute,

    CanActivateChild,
    CanDeactivate,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot
} from "@angular/router";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    MultiselectDropdownModule,
    AccordionModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  Base,
  jumping,
  players
  ],
  providers: [
  SPORTSService],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "SPORTS",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "bundle": "webpack"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "latest-version": "^2.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-expect": "^3.0.1",
    "jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-jquery": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "^0.3.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
    const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    debug: true,
    verbose: true,
    displayErrorDetails: true,
    context: __dirname,
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        reasons: true
    },
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'my-app': './src/my-app/app.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
        root: __dirname,
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'source-map-loader',
            exclude: [
                'node_modules/rxjs'
            ]
        }],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            }
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
        })
    ],

    output: {
        path: 'src',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].bundle.map',
        //chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js'
    }
};
```

**error**

```
    $ npm run bundle

> sports@1.0.0 bundle C:\Users\webcomponent\src\main\webapp
> webpack

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'displayErrorDetails'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           displayErrorDetails: ...
         }
       })
     ]
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'preLoaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, loaders?, noParse?, rules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "src" is not an absolute path!
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'modulesDirectories'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "bundle"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! sports@1.0.0 bundle: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sports@1.0.0 bundle script 'webpack'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sports package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs sports
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sports
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\webcomponent\src\main\webapp\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using new version of webpack but old version of config.
See this [article](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-preloaders-and-module-postloaders-were-removed-) to migrate or just use a new [quick start guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

Comment: hey updated my code by following your link but still I am facing same erros...providing my code change part alone which I did for plugin 

```
plugins: [
         new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
             debug: true,
            options: {
            context: __dirname
            }
        })
    ],

```

Comment: If you are not interesting in angular 2 particularly then it is not worth even trying to fix all problems (you will have more one by one) On the other hand  Angular CLI automatically creates a fully functional setup for your app. So I would recommend to go with Angular 4 instead.

Comment: is it possible to update for webpack...so that I will learn webpack too

Comment: Yes, you can use angular with webpack and they have an [official tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/webpack) for that too